# Getter function returns the wrong value?

Tags: c++, string

In my utils class I have a private solution dir string - it is set in the constructor (hardcoded). I have a getter function that returns the string. In another file I have a utils instance (pointer). When I call the getter function it returns empty.

main.cpp

```
utils* myUtils = new utils();

std::cout << myUtils->getSolutionDir() + " is the current directory" << std::endl;

delete myUtils;
```

utils.hpp

```
public:
    utils ();
    ~utils ();
    std::string getSolutionDir();
private:
    std::string _solutionDir;
```

utils.cpp

```
utils::utils () {
    std::string _solutionDir = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Coding\\CodeBlocks\\MettaRPG";
}
utils::~utils () {}

std::string utils::getSolutionDir() {
    return _solutionDir;
}
```

OUTPUT (GCC compiler):

> is the current directory

Comment: `std::string _solutionDir` in the constructor body shadows your member variable. Omit the type declaration.

Comment: is there any reason why do you use `new` and `delete` here? `utils myUtils;` and no `delete` would do as well

Comment: I wanted to pass the myUtils into another class with dependency injection. I thought that would improve performance.

Comment: I didn't post that part of the code - `maingame* myMaingame = new maingame(myUtils);`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this line in the constructor:

```
std::string _solutionDir = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Coding\\CodeBlocks\\MettaRPG";
```

This line declares a *local variable* named `_solutionDir` and sets that equal to the indicated string, rather than taking the existing data member named `_solutionDir` and changing its value. To address this, remove the `std::string` from this line.

Alternatively, if you have a C++11 compiler, consider just changing your class to look like this:

```
public:
    ~utils ();
    std::string getSolutionDir();
private:
    std::string _solutionDir = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Coding\\CodeBlocks\\MettaRPG";
```